# Create a questionnaire in Google Docs with an NA option

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to make a questionnaire in Google Docs like the example shown below?

```
3.1 Overall reactions to the system    terrible                wonderful
                                          1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9        NA
```

Using the scale option, I cannot put the NA (Not applicable) option.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the 'choose from a list', 'grid', 'checkboxes', or 'multiple choice' options?

I have created an example of your question using each of these on this [example form](https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=dE5Wby1Dcm1Od2RYSWtKZDBndkhLeGc6MQ); with [results here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?hl=en&hl=en&key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdE5Wby1Dcm1Od2RYSWtKZDBndkhLeGc&single=true&gid=0&output=html)